# Making sure questions about scripting are tagged

Tags: discussion

Murta's question about [invoking *Mathematica* from inside SQL Server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/executing-mathematica-script-from-inside-sql-server) was related to scripting as well as SQL, but it wasn't tagged as such (so I added the tag).  Only 17 questions have the scripting tag, but I'll bet there are more (untagged) questions. I haven't found much good reference material on *Mathematica* scripting. If we can find untagged scripting related questions, let's tag them.

Comment: I don't recall that many scripting questions on this site... not many seem to be using that feature. In any case, [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=script+-%5Bscript%5D+is%3Aquestion&submit=search) should help you find questions that _might_ be related to using mma scripting that don't already have the [tag:script] tag (note that a lot of them are false positives from folks using script/function/file interchangably)

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks, I'll search